# Firebase Auth Customize URL - Remove api key

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, api-key

i am setting custom url for firebase email verification url, but i dont know how to remove the api key from the url. I am storing the api key on my website in config file, so i dont need it in the URL. I am aware that api key should not pose big security risk, but i would still want to remove it and keep in the URL only necessary parameters like the mode, oobCode and lang.

Here is the example URL, i just need it without the api key:

```
https://example.com/usermgmt?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=ABC123&apiKey=AIzaSy...&lang=fr
```

I hoped this kind of thing would work, but its throwing error about reserved parameters

```
https://example.com/users?mode=%mode%&oobCode=%oobCode%&lang=%lang%
```

Comment: This is an old post, doing some searching about something very similar myself.  Is it possible in the email template to use the hyperlink text to use a more friendly version.  Dumb response right, as the key is still there just hidden a little, however I think with the right rules in place you should be able to restrict reads and/or writes as needed.